# C++ Struct defined data passing. Simple answer im sure

Tags: c++, prototype, int

I am sure this is a very simple fix and I feel dumb asking it but here it goes.

I need help with a struct and passing info from a gather function to a save or set function, and then passing it again to another function for further use.

Basically, it looks like this to start. I'll just add short snips of the code. All can be provided if you would like to see it.

I right now am just looking for the proper way to pass struct defined data from get.... to set.... functions.

```
struct printype
{   
    char dots[8][15];
    int unknown15;          //  can have values of 0..127
    string serial11_14;     //  8 characters 00000000...99999999
    int year8;              //  without century, 0..99
    int month7;             //  1..12
    int day6;               //  1..31       
    int hour5;              //  0..23       
    int minute2;            //  0..59
};  
int getunknown15();     // prototypes    
int setunknown15(int);
```

then we have a simple main.

```
int main()
{
    printype pt;
    pt.unknown15=getunknown15();
    pt.unknown15=setunknown15(12);
    pt.serial11_14=getserial11_14();
    pt.serial11_14=setserial11_14("12345678");
    pt.year8=getyear8();
    pt.year8=setyear8(44);
    pt.month7=getmonth7();
    pt.month7=setmonth7(11);
    pt.day6=getday6();
    pt.day6=setday6(12);
    pt.hour5=gethour5();
    pt.hour5=sethour5(12);
    pt.minute2=getminute2();
    pt.minute2=setminute2(23);
    cout <<"-----------------------------------------------------"<<endl;
    cout <<" Let's Get Started"<<endl;
    cout <<"-----------------------------------------------------"<<endl;
    setup(pt.dots);                         // sets up the array
    dpinfo(pt);                             // prints out the final array
    ftarray(pt);
    spar(pt.dots);
    darray(pt.dots);
}
```

and finally the get and set array functions.

```
int getunknown15()
{   
    printype tem;
    cout <<"-----------------------------------------------------"<<endl;
    cout <<" Enter the Unkown Variable (0-127):  ";  
    cin  >>tem.unknown15;
    cout <<"-----------------------------------------------------"<<endl;
    return tem.unknown15;
}
```

next is

```
int setunknown15(int tem)
{
    printype pp;


    if (tem>127||tem<0)
    {
        cout << "Error" << endl;
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        pp.unknown15 = tem;
        return pp.unknown15;
    }
}
```

I hope this isn't too much to read and understand

Anyway, I know this has a really simple answer but my brain just isn't working right now.

Comment: Perhaps there would be a really simple answer if there were a question.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the actual question?  I'm unsure what you are asking.

Comment: How did you get to structs without knowing how to pass variables?  I think what you're wanting to do is pass a pointer to the struct.

Comment: I just fixed the `void main()` problem and a few other things.  (Still not sure what's being asked.)

Comment: Sorry i didnt make this clear, i understand how to pass by ref and by all kinds of conversions. what i wanted to know what is the smartest way to pass a struct defined variable from a function to function. Should i just do a 
       struct.def=otherstruct.def
 or should i do something like passing the mem location of the get to the set function and call it good?

Answer (score 0):

Edit: As StilesCrisis stated, Send struct as parameter is quiet stupid in this case. better use a const reference.

Well, I am not sure if I understand your question correctly. You can simply send struct to another function as parameter, or as a pointer.

like:

```
void SetStruct(const printype& var);
printype GetStruct();
```

Is it what you are looking for?

Comment: Note that 99% of the time, you would be better off passing a reference, pointer, or const reference.

Comment: Oops, yeah, I agree. For the getter/setter, there is no point to pass a new struct. Guess I am too sleepy. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Please use the following access to the your fields, (by reference):

```
struct printype *myPtr = new printype;
myPtr->day6 = 43;
```

When use pointer instead of a normal variable, you should use -> instead . to access your fields.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is kind of old but I thought I should give it a shot, since you are using C++ and it looks like you are trying to use some OO practices (I think), you don't need to start with a struct, even though OO principles can be applied using them as well though not as elegantly.

you can define your class header file as such.

```
#ifndef PRINTYPE_H
#define PRINTYPE_H

#include <string>
using namespace std;

class printype
{
    private: // we always want to declare our member fields private for safety/managements reasons, no one will be able to access them outside.

        char dots[8][15];
        int unknown15;          //  can have values of 0..127
        string serial11_14;     //  8 characters 00000000...99999999
        int year8;              //  without century, 0..99
        int month7;             //  1..12
        int day6;               //  1..31       
        int hour5;              //  0..23       
        int minute2;            //  0..59

        void init(); // This is the method we use to initialize our starting state.

    public: // This is our public methods, how people deal with/get/set our state.
        printype(); // This is our default constructor
        printype(const printype& print_type); // This our copy constructor
        virtual ~printype(); // This is our destructor, its virtual, making safer for inheritance.


        // This is our setters/getters
        void setUnknown(int unknown);
        int getUnknown();                

        void setYear(int year);                    
        int getYear();

        void setMonth(int mont);
        int getMonth();

        // and well you get the idea, you can add more methods.
};  

#endif
```

and the accompanying class source file with your functions implementation

```
printype::printype() 
{
    this->init(); // Initialize all your vatiables, safer to just define a function to this.
}

printype::printype(const printype& orig)  // copy constructor
{
    this->setUknown(orig.getUnknown());
    this->setDay(orig.getDay());
    this->setDots(orig.getDots());     
    // you get the idea ...    
}

printype::~printype() 
{
    // Have anything you need to do before destroying the object.
}

void printype::init()
{
    this->setUnknwon(0);
    this->setyear(0);
    this->setMonth(1);
    char dots[8][15] = {'\0'};
    this->setDots(dots);

    // you get the idea, you want to initialize all your variables since, for the most part they initially hold garbage.
}

void printype::setUnknown(int unknown)
{
    if (unknown >= 0 && unknown < 127)
        this->unknown15 = unknown;
    else
        error("Expecting unknown to be between 0 and 127"); // error should probably print the error and/or exit(-1) up to u
}

int printype::setYear(int year) 
{
    if (year >= 1 && year <= 99)
        this->year8 = year;
    else
        error("Expecting year between 0 and 99"); // you may want to implement an error function!   
}
int printype::getYear()
{
    return this->year8;
}

void printype::setDots(char dots[8][15])
{
    // you may want to do some verifications
    memcpy(this->dots, dots, sizeof(dots));
}

void printype::setDots(char **dots) // this is a bit unsafe, use at your own risk.
{        
    if (dots)
    {
        unsigned int index = 0;
        for (index = 0; index < 8; index++)
            if (dots[index])
                memcpy(this->dots[index], dots[index], 15);
            else
                error("dots required pointer ...");
    }
    else
        error("dots required pointer ...");
}


char **getDots() // We will be returning a copy, we don't want the internal state to be affected, from outside, by using reference or pointers.
{
    char **dots = new char*[8];
    unsigned int index = 0;
    for (index = 0; index < 8; index++)
    {
        dots[index] = new char[15];
        memcpy(dots[index], this->dots[index], 15);
    }
    return dots;        
}

// and well you get the idea ...
```

to use your class

```
printype *print_type_p = new print_type();
// or 
printype pront_type_p();

// use the different public method to update the internal state.
print_type_p->setYear(3);
// or
print_type.setYear(3);
print_type_p->getYear();
// and so on.
```